# Extra large apple watch complication with color

Tags: apple-watch-complication

Does CLKComplicationTemplateExtraLargeSimpleImage support color images? It's unclear from the documentation. Here is the code snippet:

```
let template = CLKComplicationTemplateExtraLargeSimpleImage()
template.imageProvider = complicationImage // Contains colored images.
return template
```

Using multi color watch face.

The result I see on my series 4 watch is all white and no color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that it does not display color. The solution is to use CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularView instead.